# Does WorkManager have something that can post events during the task?

Tags: android

Playing around with WorkManager recently as I try to move out of using old solutions for scheduling tasks in the background.

I was wondering though, is there any sort of feature for the `Worker` to post events during it's task? I normally would use some sort of an event bus like `Otto` wherein I'd register the bus to a subclass that posts events whenever the task reaches a certain milestone.

If there is no way for `workers` to post such events during a task, is there a way for us to register the `eventBus` into the worker so we can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were no takers so I ended up finding a workaround.

Instead of posting events via an eventbus, we can observe a live `WorkStatus`.

There are a few ways to observe work statuses and in my way, I've decided to observe base on the `tag` of my worker. Below is a snippet of how I went to do this:

```
 WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusesByTag("MyWorker")
           .observe(this, new Observer<List<WorkStatus>>() {
               @Override
               public void onChanged(@Nullable List<WorkStatus> workStatuses) {
                   doSomething();
               }
           });
```

Every time something changes, I look through all of my work statuses and decide what to do. You can also grab Data values here if you ever required them.